# How to bring a group item on top of all items in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

In the [following example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/pZLBa4MwFMb/lYcXlYmobBdHdylsp8GgvVUPqT5raExCEmtH8X9fUu3GWAuF5Za8733v+z1y8jjp0Mu91R5N1XqRV4na3Q9EwS6FBXAc4E2JXgangoM9UmhqqOA5HCgOcYXcoIqmGpGSfb4To+gxh4YwjQUfw4I7k1VLJMZLqiqGFy9FatrrHJ6S2aChjC0FEyoHX2Htz8+SKDsmt4l+/D4E5WaNR3Mxq4RN4lR+i4wJGIRiNx0KfibM7iaEhwVs0iSCNCn/Sft4jfbTZR7+xM3uA6ZgWlR4q32i1QxRWuCm55XjCzodQROeNJo17VD0Jmgi6HQ4uo6zOkiTxDIHISxeYB67y+LLhs5LyawgS8q5mMZVS1lt52/SMv4mtGP9LevRvyrbKsp3a/GqLFEQPk+amwFmg99NU8nBjqH9xluFZC/dxrSXb8rxCw==), labels can't be seen at any time:

```js
var g1 = new Group({
    position: view.center,
    applyMatrix: false
})
new Shape.Circle({
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'red',
    parent: g1
})
new PointText({
    content: 'hello world',
    parent: g1
})

var g2 = new Group({
    position: view.center += [10, 10],
    applyMatrix: false
})
new Shape.Circle({
    radius: 40,
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    parent: g2
})
new PointText({
    content: 'hi there',
    parent: g2
})

var sleep = function(ms, f){setTimeout(f, ms)}

sleep(1000, () => {
    g2.position += [20, 20]
    g1.children[1].fillColor = 'blue'
    g1.children[1].bringToFront();
    sleep(1000, () => {
        g1.bringToFront()
    })
})
```

[image]

How can we keep those texts in front of any other items in the canvas at any time?

> Note: A possible solution would be getting the texts out of groups and manually positioning them. However, this will introduce huge design changes in the actual application.

Comment: I think that the workaround you are describing is the better way to do what you describe. There is no way to draw texts above circle without changing their order, this is how the library works. You can still fork the library and change its behaviour to allow doing what you want. Can you add details about your application design that prevent you from separating circles and texts (maybe there are other solutions) ?

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/ceremcem/aecad/issues/9

Comment: @sasensi Within the ["rehydration"](https://github.com/ceremcem/aecad/blob/dc9e85e1fc58c2240bf1a77fdfc8a0ea6947a240/webapps/main/sketcher/tools/lib/component-base.ls#L20-L38) process, related Paper.js items are [determined by Paper.js `item.children`](https://github.com/ceremcem/aecad/blob/dc9e85e1fc58c2240bf1a77fdfc8a0ea6947a240/webapps/main/sketcher/tools/lib/component-base.ls#L29-L38). If we separate the labels from the component group, it'll be a non-trivial task to find related parts within the project while resuming an aeCAD object.

Comment: About finding related part, maybe using [item.id](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#id) and [item.data](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#data) to create a basic relational data model could help ? E.g. `circle.data.labelId = label.id`.

Comment: Relational model will solve the case. However, as this application is used for engineering purposes, data integrity is extremely important. If anything happens while moving a "group" (app hang+crash), one piece might be moved and the other might not. This will force us to introduce a transaction semantic: First mark the group of items to be moved, then move, then clear the dirty flag. If app crashes in the process, the journal will be used to recover last action.

Comment: On second thought, even Paper.js does the ordering in its natural way, how do we export the project as SVG? SVG doesn't support such "z-index" like semantics, AFAIK. Which means, the most applicable solutions are either creating such a relational data model, or taking our chances to get a success with the blending trick as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

If changing order is really not an option, a possible workaround could be to play with colors and blend mode to make below items visible.
For example, if you have a black background, then a white text, then an orange circle on top of it, if the orange circle have a `screen` blend mode, white text will still be visible through it.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/rZPfa8IwEMf/laMv3ZjTKgije/R1gzH3MtSHNL3am2kyktSOif/7LhW1QwUHKzSl30vuPvcjm0iLCqM0mq7QyzLqRdLk4X8wgNyKBgRkSsgVZLwsral1Ds5AgyCFBocITUkeweOXn9u51tjAi/Bl/xWlF3qp8GYTdOCnsKZKYZb0IFn09qI3LI0SFnk5ygUpNTHK2BTiFiAOlu3tY/iE98h3BsCQ9m8sHGNLoz1qz97eTW1BiQwVlGgxPoT8DKcYZsgwD10UPjqlb0xHyUH7qJ2ngqTwZDQ7lewbbXwWv+W7jC/JSsVlJF+CkxZRc8WRy1xxI36VdNLu7OTUBmXicdIbdotnRU61S2GcnAUylhvTSbwN98zR2LYjuI5WG1sJ9Wfa4T/i7hAu4ZJ23tYy9MhdNRtPWPh9iqVwnO9JR8L0h1kDcrAmR2wBXPMWKoBalSfLcGx/Mllrwqa/KwPctffgftwpw4WZ6uTGtzOzKFatPxels8X2Bw==) demonstrating the solution.

```
// draw a black background so we can see white text
new Path.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [200, 200],
    fillColor: 'black'
});

// draw a white text
new PointText({
    content: 'Your label here',
    point: [100,80],
    fontSize:20,
    justification: 'center',
    fillColor: 'white'
});

// draw a circle with screen blend mode
new Path.Circle({
    center: [50,100],
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    blendMode: 'screen'
});

// draw a circle with normal blend mode
new Path.Circle({
    center: [150,100],
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    blendMode: 'normal'
});

// draw instructions
new PointText({
    content: 'Left circle has a screen blend mode so text is visible even if it is below it',
    point: view.center + [0, -50],
    justification: 'center'
});
```

[image]